# Minimizing and Maximizing <div>

Tags: javascript, html, css, jsp

Referring various sources, I've written a code to minimize and maximize a div tag in my JSP code which goes as follows,

```
<style type="text/css" media="screen" > #editor {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 20%;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
}

#widnow {
    position: absolute;
    top: 72.5%;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: auto;
    border: solid 1px;
}

#title_bar {
    background: #FEFEFE;
    height: 25px;
    width: 100%;
}

#button {
    border: solid 1px;
    width: 25px;
    height: 23px;
    float: right;
    cursor: pointer;
}

#box {
    height: 250px;
    background: #DFDFDF;
}

</style >
```

=============================

```
<div id="widnow">
    <div id="title_bar">
        <div id="button">-</div>
    </div>
    <div id="box">
    </div>
</div>
```

============================

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$("#button").click(function(){
    if($(this).html() == "-"){
        $(this).html("+");
    }
    else{
        $(this).html("-");
    }
    $("#box").slideToggle();
});
</script>
```

This gives me a div tag something like this,

[image]

But when I click the minimize button (i.e - on the top right) nothing happens.
The code works fine as shown in this [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/miqdad/Qy6Sj/1/) but does not work in my jsp.

what to do? where is my mistake?

Comment: are you included jquery ?

Comment: can u provide rendered html code or any link

Comment: @Shafeeq Yes, I've included  <script src="js/jquery.autocomplete.js"></script>

Comment: your jsfiddle works for me in chrome

Comment: The code works as shown in demo, but failed to work in my servlet. Please check my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removed

```
<script src="js/jquery.autocomplete.js"></script>
```

from head in JSP and added

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

This worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

Did you Check for JavaScript conflicts? I had such issues before.